# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, why?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

This is my App.js file. I am trying to fetch data using fetch()
   What am I missing? Getting Error as TypeError: Cannot read property 
   map of undefined". What is wrong? How do I get the result?
   I'm following the reactjs tutorial, and I keep running into an issue 
   when passing the value from the state of one component into another 
   component. The error 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' is thrown 
   when the map function in the CommentList component is executed. What 
   would cause the prop to become undefined when fetching data? I also 
   tried putting debugger, why it is not going inside the fetch call?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UsingFetch from './UsingFetch'; 

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      companyList:[]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => { res.json() })
      .then(
        res => {
          this.setState({
            companyList : res
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        1) DataGrid
        <UsingFetch datasource = {this.state.companyList}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my UsingFetch.js File

```
class UsingFetch extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoaded:false,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.datasource.map(item =>
          <div>
            {item.name}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is my App.js and UsingFetch.js file. I am trying to fetch data 
  using fetch(), What am I missing? Getting Error as:

> TypeError: Cannot read property    map of undefined"

What is wrong? How do I get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not returning anything from first `then` block. So `res` in second `then` block is `undefined`. you should use `return` in

```
then(res => { res.json() })
```

Change to

```
then(res => res.json())
```

or

```
then(res => { return res.json() })
```

Comment: Thanks.Can you help me with reading local json. App.js and data.js are in the same folder.
fetch('../data.js')
      .then(res => {console.log(res); return  res.json()});     
data.js is :
const customers = [
    {'ID': 1,
    'City': 'Bentonville'
  }];
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: you can just keep `[{'ID': 1, 'City': 'Bentonville' }];` in 'data.js'. And `import data from './data.js'` in 'App.js'. And  'data.js' should also be in `src` folder. Or you can use [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server)

Comment: using import it is working properly. But I need to read it using fetch. Use fetch to read local file is the requirement. data.json is in source file and App.js also Thanks!

Comment: i think you might be using `create-react-app`. so using `fetch` might not possibe. Can you go to `Network` tab in browser and click in `data.js` to see the response. you might be getting html as response.

Comment: if you really want to use `fetch` then you need to `eject` the app and change the `webpack-dev-server` config. As it serves the html file for every request. Or you can simply use `json-server`.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using your isLoaded anywhere in your component?  You also aren't passing anything into it.  You should pass your state down and then assign it in setState.

In your App:

```
<UsingFetch datasource = {this.state.companyList} isLoaded={this.state.isLoaded}/>
```

And in your UsingFetch

```
constructor(){
  super();

   this.state = {
      isLoaded:this.props.isLoaded,
 }
   }
```

Or just check to see if the datasource is there or isLoaded.

```
<div>
{this.props.datasource && this.props.isLoaded?
<React.Fragment>
                     {this.props.datasource.map(item =>
                     <div>
                         {item.name}
                     </div>
                     )}
 </React.Fragment>
:
<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>
```