# Can't pass this error with Vanilla JS: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use OMDb API, and I keep getting this error. Followed all the steps from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWg2udweauY&feature=emb_logo) YT video and I can't find the answer. It worked before I changed the code to declare moviesection() function outside of the createMovieContainer() . Here is my code:

```js
let movieSearchable = document.querySelector('.movies-searchable')
let buttonElement = document.querySelector('#search');
const url = " http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=45ddf1ee&s=";
const posterURL = "http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=45ddf1ee&";
const apiKey = "45ddf1ee";

function movieSection(movies) {
  return movies.map((movie) => {
    return `
    <img src=${movie.Poster} data-movie-id=${movie.Title}/>
    `
  });
}

function createMovieContainer(movies) {
  let movieElement = document.createElement('div');
  movieElement.setAttribute('class', 'movie');
  let movieTemplate = `<section class="section">
  ${movieSection(movies)}
  </section>
  <div class="content">
      <p id="content-close">
          X
      </p>
  </div>
  `;
  movieElement.innerHtml = movieTemplate;
  return movieElement;
}

buttonElement.onclick = function(event) {
  let value = form.value;
  let newUrl = url + value;
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch(newUrl)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let movies = data.results;
      let movieBlock = createMovieContainer(movies);
      movieSearchable.appendChild(movieBlock);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error: ', err);
    })
}
```

Comment: The error means that `data.results` is not defined. Use `console.log(data)` to see the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624980/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-why)

Comment: Change the line to `let movies = data.Search;` The json response does not have a key named `results`. You can see here for yourself: http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=45ddf1ee&s=test

Comment: It stays undefined, even though I change it to `data.results`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API that you mentioned returns a response like this:

```
{
  "Search": [
    {
      "Title": "Hello, My Name Is Doris",
      "Year": "2015",
      "imdbID": "tt3766394",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg0NTM3MTI1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTAzNTAzNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "totalResults": "592",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

So, the movies exist in a property `Search` of the response object - not in `results`.

Therefore, `data.results` is `undefined`. You then go on passing that `undefined` as `movies` argument into `createMovieContainer`, and from there into `movieSection`. Finally you call `movies.map(...)` which is essentially `undefined.map(...)` at that point, and because `undefined` doesn't have properties, the computer cannot read the `map` property of `undefined` that you are attempting to use, hence the error.

The fix: Change `data.results` to `data.Search`.

A word of advice: Next time, use a debugger. See what the values of your variables are when the error happens - you'd have noticed that `movies` is `undefined`. Then trace back where those values came from - you'd have noticed that the `undefined` came from `data.results`, and you'd have seen the actual structure of `data` and that the movies array is called `Search`.

Comment: Movies stay undefined when I change `data.results` to `data.Search`

Comment: But, when I run `fetch("https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=45ddf1ee&s=hello").then(r => r.json()).then(r => console.log(r.Search))` in the console, I get an array with 10 movies, not `undefined`...

Comment: So now would be the right time to [start using a debugger](https://flaviocopes.com/react-debugging/) and step through your code to see why you still get `undefined`.